# Align Progress Bar Bootstrap 4 (centered value) with button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been struggling for some time now with aligning the Bootstrap Progress Bar with a Button.

I want the button on the right side aligned and the value on the progress centered but I can't get both at the same time. See the 2 results I get:

[image]

[image]

The code for the first one is:

**PHP:**

```
<div class="col-6 progress-container">
<div class="d-inline-flex progress progress-bar-size m-2">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width:25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
<span class="text-dark ml-1"><strong>25%</strong></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-inline-flex">
<form class="form-group" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.progress-container { margin-left: auto;  margin-right:auto;}

.progress-bar-size{ height: 25px; width: 75%;}
```

There's only one change between both examples; In the second one I've added the classes "justify-content-center position-absolute w-75" to the "span" item to center the value but that brings the button down.

I've created 2 fiddles:

[Button Aligned](https://jsfiddle.net/xqoszc42/)

[Value Centered](https://jsfiddle.net/29mx0zys/)

Any ideas on how to get both things, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the `.progress-bar-size`. You need to do this because your elements are `inline-flex`.

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uopf7dgt/)

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!